# Grails app running on Windows 64 bit and Java 32bit

Tags: java, grails, grails-2.0

Running a grails app on 64bit computer with JAVA_HOME set to a 32 bit version of java. When the controller executes an external groovy command I get the error below

```
"
Unrecognized option: -noverify
error: jvm creation failed with code -1: unknown error"
```

Comment: what do you mean by `controller executes external groovy command`? can you provide some examples?

Comment: The controller runs an external groovy command through cmd.execute() where cmd is "groovy myscript.groovy ..."

Answer (score 0):

On a 64 bit OS **always** use an 64 bit JVM. Otherwise you can run into strange problems like the one you experience above.